# Binomial Series and the nth derivative

Tags: binomial-theorem

When differentiating a binomial series of the form $(1+x)^k$, why is the the $n$th derivative equal to $k(k-1) ... (k-n+1)$? I don't understand where there is $+1$ in the end of $(k-n+1)$ is coming from.

Comment: The $n$-th derivative is actually $k(k-1)\cdots(k-n+1)(1+x)^{k-n}$ (for $n\le k$).

Comment: Don‘t you see this easy pattern? Study the second derivative!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The product contains $n$ terms since you've differentiated $n$ times. But the numbers subtracted from $k$ in each factor begins at $0,$ not $1.$ Hence the last factor is $$k-(n-1)=k-n+1.$$

Comment: Makes sense! Thank you.